# sonar variable reference

Tags: properties, sonarqube

I have the following sonar properties file:

```
...  
sonar.modules=my.really.long.module.prefix/sub1,my.really.long.module.prefix/sub2
...
```

I want to reference a variable such as:

```
my.key= my.really.long.module.prefix
```

and reference it like this:

```
sonar.modules=${my.key}/sub1,${my.key}/sub2
```

However when I run this via `sonar-runner` on the command line it does not properly substitute `${my.key}` .  How can i make this substitution happen?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported yet.

Feel free to come on the Sonar user mailing list and discuss this matter, as it could be something we might consider.

Comment: link to mailing list?  I want to make sure I don't go to the wrong one

Comment: user AT sonar.codehaus.org, as explained here: http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/

Answer (score 0):

sonar scanner now supports variable substitution, as described in the question.

Tested using version 5.0.1.3006 of the scanner.

Unfortunately, I can't find it in the scanner documentation.
According to https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/SQSCANNER/issues/SQSCANNER-9 it was changed in 2017 version 2.9 of the scanner